# I cannot use my Custom Authorize attribute if put in an external assembly

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

I am using a custom AuthorizeAttribute in my Mvc4 project:

```
public sealed class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(){}

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Security stuff here...
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Then I decorate controller actions with this attribute:

```
[ClaimsAuthorize(Roles = "Developers")]
public ActionResult Authorize()
{
    return View();
}
```

If I put the attribute class into my MVC project everything works as expected.

However, if I put the attribute class into an external assembly referenced by my mvc project, nothing happens. The namespace are the same in both cases. The references of my external assembly project contains System.Web and System.Web.Mvc.

I can't see what's missing. Any idea someone?

Comment: What does it not do, or what error do you get and are you use you don't have the same class in both projects?

Comment: This should definitely work--I've done this exact thing, i.e. a custom authorize attribute in a separate assembly. Clarify what you mean by "nothing happens". Can you hit a breakpoint inside the custom attribute?

Comment: There is no error and I cannot reach a breakpoint in the overriden AutorizeCore() method, that's what surprises me. Yes, the class is exactly the same (copy/paste).

Comment: You may be confusing the compiler/IDE because you now have two components with the same namespace.  You can search your namespaces to see if you can find the hierarchy to your attribute in the object browser by pressing CTRL + ALT + J.  Because the DLL is separate from the main project, A different sub-namespace is preferred.  If your project is in the namespace `Project`, your assembly's namespace should be something like `Project.Project2`

Comment: Even if I keep a single attribute class and change its namespace in the external dll, the class is loaded but the breakpoint in AuthorizeCore() is never hit. Besides, I added a Class with a TestMethod() in the same namespace and I can call it from the action method whitout problem. So is doesn't look like a reference or namespace problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what was happening: the mvc project and the external assembly were referencing different minor versions of System.Web.Mvc (4.0.3 and 4.0.4, thank you Reflector!)

The external library project containing my ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute class had the Specific version property set to true on its reference to System.Web.Mvc. I just set it to false and everything is working fine now!